# How to install Inkscape 0.48 release on older releases?

Tags: software-installation, 10.04, 10.10, inkscape, 9.10

What's the right way to install Inkscape 0.48 on a Ubuntu Karmic/Lucid/Maverick installation?

There are only older versions available in the ubuntu repositories.

- karmic: 0.47~pre4-0ubuntu1
- lucid: 0.47.0-2ubuntu2
- maverick: 0.47.0-2ubuntu3

I know there is a [ppa](https://edge.launchpad.net/~inkscape-nightly/+archive/ppa) with the latest version, but this ppa only covers the nightly builds and not the latest stable 0.48 version of inkscape.

Yesterday I tried to compile it on a Ubuntu 9.10 box, but there are too many dependencies so I gave up.

Are there plans to integrate the latest 0.48 release in the maverick packages?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [semi-official](https://edge.launchpad.net/~zyv/+archive/inkscape-backports) looking PPA with backports of Inkscape .48.

Unfortunately the latest version I have in Maverick as of today is .47, the merge for .48 has been approved and it .48 should be in Maverick soonish.

Comment: Are there plans to include version .48 in karmic/lucid backports?

Comment: No clue, you can request it here though: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Answer (score 0):

There is also always the option of building from source. You can download the tarball of .48 here http://inkscape.org/download/. Then [this page](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/CompilingUbuntu) will walk you through the compile.